# *ngIf for style tag

Tags: css, angular-ng-if

My problem does not appear to be solvable by using traditional ways of conditional styling, like `[ngStyle]` or `[ngClass]`. I want to conditionally define a CSS-selector using `:host ::ng-deep`, for example:

```
<style *ngIf='preventXScroll'>
    :host ::ng-deep .p-datatable-wrapper {overflow-x: hidden !important;}
</style>
```

But doing it this way always applies the style, regardless of the actual state of `preventXScroll`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem can be solved via `[ngClass]`.

Template:

```
<div class='outer-wrapper' [ngClass]='{"prevent-x-scroll": preventXScroll}'>
    <p-table>
        ...
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
:host ::ng-deep .prevent-x-scroll .p-datatable-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

This way the style is only applied to `p-datatable-wrapper` (within `p-table` child component) while it is contained in `prevent-x-scroll`.